# Can't find "Android mode" on the Processing IDE - Linux

Tags: android, linux, ide, processing, xubuntu

I'm trying to install the Android Mode on the Processing IDE, however I can't seem to find it on the IDE and everyone I've download from the internet is for the windows version. I'm working on Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need the solution. In Processing 3 the steps are -

1. Open the PDE

[image]

2. Click on the arrow near the `Java` in the top right. The Contribution Manager will open.

[image]

3. Click on the Android Mode to activate the install button and install the mode.

[image]